# Can't execute script if session not set

Tags: php, session

Good morning, I am trying to develop a link shortener system with statistics in php (5.6). One of these stats is the number of sessions. I am trying to use this logic:

```
if session doesn't exist
    start the session
    add +1 to the session field and +1 to the click field
else
    just add +1 to the click field.
```

With my first approach i tried to put session_start in the middle of the code and it didn't work. I realized I can't do it and I moved the statement in the first line of the code, making a big if condition.

```
<?php if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE) { session_start();
    ...config and stuff...
    $pdo->query("UPDATE links SET session = session + 1 WHERE slug = '$slug'");
    $pdo->query("UPDATE links SET click = click + 1 WHERE slug = '$slug'");
    } else {
    ...config and stuff...
    $pdo->query("UPDATE links SET click = click + 1 WHERE slug = '$slug'");
    }
?>
```

When I debug this the session field is always updated, but it should increase only the first time. What am I missing?

Side note: this is the redirect page, i don't know if it is a useful info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`session_status` shows only status of current session, not if user has ever started a session. That's why your `session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE` are always true on first requests execution of that if statement.

Maybe you want to do something like storing some flag in session to indicate if it's user's first visit or not

```php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['initialized'])) {
    $_SESSION['initialized'] = time();
    ...config and stuff...
    $pdo->query("UPDATE links SET session = session + 1 WHERE slug = '$slug'");
    $pdo->query("UPDATE links SET click = click + 1 WHERE slug = '$slug'");
} else {
    ...config and stuff...
    $pdo->query("UPDATE links SET click = click + 1 WHERE slug = '$slug'");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE` will always result in true before the session is actually started.
You should use a flag instead. Just put `session_start` on the first line and do something like:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['flag'])) {
       $stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE links SET session = session + 1 WHERE slug = :slug");
       $stmt->execute([':slug' => $slug, ]);
       $_SESSION['flag'] = true;
    }
    
    $stmt = $pdo->query("UPDATE links SET click = click + 1 WHERE slug = :slug");
    $stmt->execute([':slug' => $slug, ]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you and Justinas replied in sync. You also reminded me the proper way to prepare and execute a PDO query with variables.